# How to map controls to physical keyboard locations

Tags: qt, boost, keyboard, sfml

I've been wanting to create a game engine, but I want to sort out some issues such as how to do controls.  Is it possible to map controls to the physical locations on the keyboard as opposed to the individual keys themselves?

I would like to do this because I think that simply configuring to controls like "W" for up and "S" for down is a nuisance for anyone who isn't using qwerty and needs to reconfigure to the locations intended by the creators of a game, which would include Dvorak users like myself or anyone who just decides to change the system default.

I'll probably be using C++ with Boost, SFML and Qt if that matters.

Comment: Even though "WASD" keys map to different letters on a Dvorak keyboard if you used key locations I would still have to reconfigure for myself since I prefer to use "ESDF" as I am a touch typist and this keeps my fingers comfortably on the "home" row. I don't think I would enjoy trying to choose "fourth key from the left on the third row from the top" instead of just "E". Also, the physical layout of all the keyboards out there are by no means universal :)

Comment: @Arnold Spence I think you're missing my point.  I want to create an abstraction between keys and the underlying hardware for making configurations themselves agnostic to different layouts.  By no means should ease of use be impacted.  So while you would configure "E" to do something in a game, in actuality you're setting "fourth key from the left on the third row from the top".  So in QWERTY "E" is "Location1", but if you were to change to Dvorak then "." is "Location1". This also brings up the point that keys are probably irrelevant to touch typists.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do it would to simply have the controls in a .ini or text file, and then the user can configure it from there. Or else, a menu in the game from which you can select a key. i.e. "Press the key for up" etc. In terms of physical layouts, there aren't really any standards.

Anyway, even those using qwerty keyboards way want to customise their keys e.g. roguelike keys.

Comment: I am aware that keyboard layouts are not universal-- being able to abstract those differences away is an overlapping issue I want to solve. I would also like to point out that I'm not trying to restrict customization, as I too like to change defaults even when using QWERTY.

Comment: In that case, can't you just specify different initial key settings for each kind of keyboard?

Comment: I don't see why not. I would like to set initial defaults like with any traditional game, but I'm hoping to find a way for the keys to automatically reconfigure themselves with no user interaction based on the layouts and different hardware setups. I simply want a more consistent design rather than an ad-hoc solution if it means more convenience for users now and users in the future.